# Shorter code for Angular 2 new FormControl()

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm hardliner in DRY (don't repeat yourself) concept. Right now I'm researching on Angular 2 API Reference and cant found the shorter way to create form :

```
import {Component, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {EmployeeSharedService} from "../employee-shared.service";
import {Employee} from "../employee";
import {EmployeeService} from "../employee.service";
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'employee-detail',
  providers: [ EmployeeService, CityService ],
  templateUrl: './employee-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-detail.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeService, private cityService:CityService, private employeeSharedService:EmployeeSharedService) { }

  createForm() { // how to shorten this?
    this.employeeForm = new FormGroup({
      empId:new FormControl(),
      firstName:new FormControl(),
      lastName:new FormControl(),
      gender:new FormControl(),
      dateOfBirth:new FormControl(),
      nationality:new FormControl(),
      maritalStatus:new FormControl(),
      phone:new FormControl(),
      city:new FormControl(),
      subDivision:new FormControl(),
      status:new FormControl(),
      suspendDate:new FormControl(),
      hiredDate:new FormControl(),
      grade:new FormControl(),
      division:new FormControl(),
      email:new FormControl()
    });
  }

  setFormValue() {    // see, this is can be shortened
    this.employeeForm.setValue(this.selectedEmployee);
  }

  resetFormValue() {  // see, this is can be shortened
    this.employeeForm.reset(this.selectedEmployee);
  }

  nullifyFormValue() {   // see, this is can be shortened
    this.employeeForm.reset(new Employee());
  }
}
```

Since I already have class Employee like this

```
export class Employee {
  empId?:number;
  firstName:string;
  lastName:string;
  gender:string;
  dateOfBirth:Date;
  nationality:string;
  maritalStatus:string;
  phone:string;
  city: City;
  subDivision:string;
  status:string;
  suspendDate:Date;
  hiredDate:Date;
  grade:string;
  division:string;
  email:string;
  profilePicture?:string;
}
```

I can shorten reset form or set value. But how to shorten form creation?

Answer (score 1):

Use the FormBuilder:

```
....
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
.....

constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeService, private cityService:CityService, private employeeSharedService:EmployeeSharedService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  createForm() { // how to shorten this?
    this.employeeForm = this.fb.group({
      empId: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName:'',
       .....
    });
   .....
```

[Check out the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html) to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following could be what you are looking for.

Change to interfaces instead :) Creating an instance of that interface can be done like: `employee: Employee: <Employee>{}`, but that won't give the property keys you are looking for, so let's create a function that does that. The code samples below are shortened from yours. The function:

```ts
export function createEmployee(empId?:number,firstName?:string): Employee {
  return {
    empId,
    firstName
  }
}
```

import that function to your component and create an employee:

```ts
employee = createEmployee();
```

Now we have the properties we can iterate and create the form based on them:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.employeeForm = new FormGroup({});
  this.setValues();
}

setValues() {
  for(let key in this.employee) {
    this.employeeForm.addControl(key, new FormControl(''))
  }
}
```

Now we have all formfields, now you could of course write in your template all the different `formControlName`'s longhand. Maybe you want to shorten that as well?

Create a pipe, that will iterate the formgroup:

```ts
@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value)
    }
}
```

And then the template let's use it:

```html
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm">
  <div *ngFor="let key of employeeForm.controls | keys">
    <label>{{key}}: </label>
    <input [formControlName]="key" />
  </div>
</form>
```

But as said, you can also skip the iteration of the form and write them longhand :)

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KKkJqR4ey3fcgzK0aptm?p=preview)

Comment: Hey, what did you think about the answers provided, Did either satisfy you, or are you looking for something else? :)